# Number that is co-prime with all numbers in list

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Cosider a set of $n$ distinct elements set $=$ { $a_i$ for all 0$<$ i$< $$n$$+1$ and also $a_i$ $!=0$} find a number that minimum $x$ (x $!=$ 0) such that for all i $<$ $n+1$, $a_i$%$x$ !=0

How can i find such an x?

for example set={10,6,8,77} minimum possible x is $x$$=$$9$.

Comment: Well, not if one of the $a_i=0$.  If you exclude that, then just take any $x>\max (|a_i|)$, no?

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity.  Having found a single $x$ that works, $\max (|a_i|)+1$ for instance, then it's just a simple finite search.

Comment: @lulu we need to find minimum x with that criteria

Comment: Yes, a finite search would do that.  Or you could simply enumerate the factors of each of the $a_i$ and do a sieve.  Really not sure what you are hoping for.

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you added some context.  What is the source of this problem?  It looks like something from a programming competition, is it?  What size are you expecting for the $a_i$?  If they are all huge numbers then factoring is certainly not a useful suggestion (nor would my finite search work terribly well).

Comment: Your title asks a different question. For instance, in your example, $9$ is not co-prime with $6$.

Comment: To clarify:  my interpretation was for the question in the body.  The header question is very different.  For that one, the answer is clearly a prime:  if $n$ is some integer prime to each of the $a_i$ then so is any prime which divides $n$.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've understood your question but apologies in advance if I have misunderstood some of the symbols you used in the post.

Let  $p_i$ be the $i$th prime. Let $p_{k+1}$ be the first prime which is **not** a factor of any $a_i$ and, for $1\le i\le k$, let $P_i$ be the smallest power of $p_i$ which does **not** divide any $a_i$.

The number you require is then either the least one of $P_1,P_2, ..., P_k,p_{k+1}$ or some other combination of  powers of the $p_i$s which is even smaller - these require individual checks unless someone can spot a quicker way of dealing with them! (See the comments by @lulu.)

> Example $\{10,6,8,77\}$

Then $P_1,P_2, ..., P_k,p_{k+1}=16,9,25,49,121,13$ and so the number you require is $9$. (Note that the only other possible combination of prime powers less than $9$ is $6$, but this divides one of the numbers.)

Comment: You are saying that the least such $x$ must always be a prime power?  But consider the list $\{2,3,4,5\}$.  The least good $x$ is, of course, $6$.  Your method returns $7$, does it not?

Comment: Yes my method does return 7. I'm still not totally convinced that I understand the question but I'll try to adapt my answer.

Comment: I think the question is clear, no?  Though I doubt there is any sort of convenient answer.  A finite search certainly works...for each $x=\{2,3,\cdots\}$ just test to see if $x\,|\,a_i$ for some $i$, if it does not, stop, if not, move to $x+1$.  If you had all the prime factorizations of the $a_i$ that would certainly help.   Neither method is practical if the $a_i$ are hundreds of digits long, of course.

Comment: I think your interpretation is clear but it isn't what the other answer is using or what the title says.

Comment: Ah, you are right about that. My interpretation is for the question in the body.  For the header question, the answer is clearly a prime (since if $x$ is prime to some list of numbers then so is any prime which divides $x$).

Comment: I also was guessing what a%x! means but is that printed out correctly on your computer? I think I've seen it before - is it a version of Latex?

Comment: I don't see that particular syntax in the post.  I believe the OP is using "$!=$" for "$\neq$".  I do see the notation "$a\%x!=0$" which I interpret as "$a\not \equiv 0 \pmod x$".

Comment: Typo on my part but thanks - I'm sure you're right.

Comment: @lulu, I think your finite search is eminently practical for very large numbers, as long as the list is not too long. You won't have to try many numbers. The prime factorisations might be useful if you were given them for free, but you certainly don't need them.

Comment: @TonyK  At least, I haven't got anything better.  You can probably speed the search by keeping track of the numbers which fail to divide some case. If $6\nmid a_1$ then there is no need to test $12$ on $a_1$ and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you want a $t$ such that
$$\forall i; t\not\equiv 0 \pmod{a_i}$$
 Taking $$t=1+\prod_{i=0}^{n+1}a_i$$
immediately gives $$\forall i; t\equiv 1\pmod{a_i}$$ and so satisfies.

Comment: The question is to find minimum x

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative answer better suited to computer use.

Let $p_i$ be the $i$th prime and let $F_k(a_1,a_2,...)$ be the smallest possible $x$ which is **not** divisible by any $p_i$, for $i<k$. We require $F_1(a_1,a_2,...)$.

For a particular $p_k$, let $b_i$ be the largest factor of $a_i$ which is coprime to $p_k$  and let the $c_i$ be the $a_i$ which are divisible by $p_k$.

> Then $F_k(a_1,a_2,...)$ is the lesser of  $F_{k+1}(b_1,b_2,...)$ and $p_kF_k(\frac {c_1}{p_k},\frac {c_2}{p_k}, ...)$

**Proof**

The first expression is the minimum $x$ which does not have $p_k$ as a factor and the second expression is the minimum $x$ which does have $p_k$ as a factor.

This gives us a recursive method for finding $x$ which involves dividing  by a non-decreasing sequence of primes and  is therefore reasonably fast.

> Example $\{6,8,10,77\}$

$$F_1(6,8,10,77)=\min \{F_2(3,5,77),2F_1(3,4,5)\}$$
$$F_2(3,5,77)=\min \{F_3(5,77),3F_2(1)\}=\min \{11,9\}=9$$
$$2F_1(3,4,5)=\min \{2F_2(3,5),4F_1(2)\}=\min \{14,12\}=12$$
Therefore
$$F_1(6,8,10,77)=9.$$

Comment: @lulu  I think this is reasonably fast for a computer to perform.